# How to split a shapefile compose of multiple linestrings

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a shapefile of a regional network constructed composed of 4000 features (lines). I would like to split lines longer than 500 meters in order to obtain a maximum length of 500 meters for each line. For example, for a line of 7 km, it is necessary to cut 14 parts and each one has to maintain the same attributes of the original.

I try with function `cut` from Shapely but it doesn't work because I need to separate the geometry of the features in the geodataframe to cut the line.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you are trying and explain in more details why it doesn't work?

Comment: What about going over each **feature** and construct a new **line** object using the **coordinates**? Keep appending the coordinates to it while checking the **length** and once it hits **500m** remove the last point, add the line to the collection and start a new line.

Comment: Do you have some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem I decide to develop a function to cut a line in multiple lines according to number of pieces.

First of all I checked "cut" function from shapely users manual (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html). This function allows to cut a line (LineString) in two parts with the line and the distance as arguments

```
 def cut(line, distance):
 # Cuts a line in two at a distance from its starting point
 if distance <= 0.0 or distance >= line.length:
      return [LineString(line)]
 coords = list(line.coords)
 for i, p in enumerate(coords):
      pd = line.project(Point(p))
      if pd == distance:
          return [
                  LineString(coords[:i+1]),
                  LineString(coords[i:])]
      if pd > distance:
          cp = line.interpolate(distance)
          return [
                   LineString(coords[:i] + [(cp.x, cp.y)]),
                   LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:])]
```

Then, I use this function to cut a LineString multiple times using the argument pieces and the line. Pieces is use to divided the length of the line in equal parts in order to cut the line.

## MultiCut is define with the line to cut and the number of pieces that you want to obtain from the line

```
def MultiCut(line, pieces):

#Firts we need to define two list to append the results (lines) and the lines to cut
lines_result = [] #All the lines are add to this list
lines_to_cut = [] #The lines to cut are add to this list

#We must ensure that pieces are higher than 2
if pieces == 1: #If pieces are 1 the result is the same line
    lines_result.append(line) 
elif pieces == 2: #If pieces are 2 the result is the line cut by the middle point
    distance = (line.length)/pieces
    lines_result.append(cut(line, distance)[0])
    lines_result.append(cut(line, distance)[1])
else: # If pieces is more than 3 we star to cut the line in the number of pieces
    # We use a loop  from the first to the penultimate piece 
    for i in range(1, pieces): 
        # The first piece is cut to save the result and the rest of the line
        if i == 1:
            distance = (line.length)/pieces #Distance is calculate as the lenght of the line divided by the number of pieces
            lines_result.append(cut(line, distance)[0]) #We cut the line and 
            save the first part in lines result
            lines_to_cut = cut(line, distance)[1] #We save the rest of the line in lines to cut in order to continue with the split

        #If pieces are equal to pieces minus two we can split the line and 
        #save only the first part in lines result in order to continue with 
        #the split
        if  1 < i <= pieces - 2:
            distance = (line.length)/pieces
            lines_result.append(cut(lines_to_cut, distance)[0])
            lines_to_cut = cut(lines_to_cut, distance)[1]

        #Finally if pieces are equal to pieces minus 1 we can cut the line 
        #and save both of the parts in lines result
        if (i != 1) and (i == pieces-1):
            distance = (line.length)/pieces
            lines_result.append(cut(lines_to_cut, distance)[0])
            lines_result.append(cut(lines_to_cut, distance)[1])

return lines_result
```

Finally we have the line cut in the number of pieces that you want. For example if you have a line of 5 units:

```
 line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)])
```

You can split the line with cut using a distance

```
cut(line, 2.5)
```

Or, you can use MultiCut to split the line in the number of pieces that you need

```
MultiCut(line, 2) #Cut the line by middle
MultiCut(line, 5) #Cut the line in five parts with 1 as distance
```

Because I need to cut a shapefile in many lines, I use MultiCut in a loop to did that.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry as geom
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

#I read the shapefile with geopandas
df = gpd.read_file('Red_local_Samana.shp')
#I project the shapefile 
df = df.to_crs("EPSG:3115")
#I took the lines (LineString) of the geodataframe 
network_to_cut = df.geometry

results = []
for j in range(0, len(network_to_cut)):

    if network_to_cut[j].length > 500:

        line = network_to_cut[j]
        pieces = int(((line.length)//500)+1)
        results.append(list(MultiCut(line, pieces)))
```

With this methodology I split all the lines in my shapefile higher than 500 meters in pieces at least of 500 meters